# Rails 3 Render / Partial

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm very new to Rails 3 and I've followed some tutorials and now I'm trying to "play" with the code created. I have followed the tutorial from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I'm am trying to render the form for new posts on the homepage with this code:

```
<%= render :partial => "posts/form" %>
```

The posts/_form.html.erb looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and this is the error I get:

```
 undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @post.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/home/index.html.erb

Rails.root: d:/server/cazare

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_posts__form_html_erb___794893824_70478136_519766'
app/views/home/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb__967672939_70487520_0'
```

I understand that this may seem a piece of cake for some of you but I'm trying to understand how everything works on Rails so I hope you can understand me.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you get an error or what is the problem?

Comment: That piece of code (the call to `model_name`) is nowhere in the code you posted. You need to look at the error, as it should give you a filename and line number, and post that section of code, and tell us specifically what line it's occurring on.

Comment: I've updated the post with the error. Sorry about not posting in the first place.

Comment: As Andrew above have noted, your code must be referring to a method called "model_name" somewhere. Search your code and try to find where. You can also post the stack trace here, so it will be easy for people to debug your code.

Comment: I've posted a full error message in the original text and I've also searched for model_name and there is nowhere in my code...

Comment: @thekindofme, model_name is a deprecated Rails function [http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/model_name](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/model_name)

Comment: @nash - no, it's just moved: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Naming/model_name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@post variable is not instantiated in the Controller :)

so `"@post = Post.new"`  inside the controller action should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Rails is attempting to build a form for the object `@post`. In order to do that, it needs to know what sort of object `@post` is; that way, it can find any existing data in the object and fill it into the form for you. Rails has a method grafted on to objects called `model_name` to do the lookup, but it won't be grafted onto `NilClass` (the class of the `nil` object).

I suspect that you haven't defined `@post` anywhere - it's an instance variable of the Controller, so you'd expect the controller to either find `@post` from the database, or to call `@post = Post.new` - so it's `nil`.

Comment: I've figured it out finally, well I don't know how things work right now but you are right, I didn't defined @post in my home#index controller.

Answer (score 0):

In the posts/_form.html.erb,

change

```
 <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for(Post.new) do |f| %>
```